# How do I identify a particular residual from a mixed-effects model in R?

Tags: r, residuals, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Here's a plot of my residuals from a mixed-effects model in R (using lme4).

[image: Residuals]

There's one 'outlying' residual with a value of around 35 (index circa 90) that seems anomalous. I don't know if it has any statistical significance (any advice of that would be appreciated) but I'm curious if perhaps I've made an error entering that data point... **but how can I find out what the record number for that observation is in my original data set?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that illustrates how to find the indices of observations based on residuals.

An example:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
plot(residuals(fm1))
```

[image]

There are two residuals with a absolute value above 100. You can use `which` to obtain the indices.

```
which(residuals(fm1) > 100)
# 57 
# 57 
which(residuals(fm1) < -100)
# 8
# 8
```

The numbers appear twice because the function `residuals` returns a named vector, and the names are the indices.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility (you may need the development version of `lme4`, installable via `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")`) is

```
plot(fm1,id=0.05,idLabels=~.obs)
```

which will add observation-number labels to all observations in the 5% Normal tail of the residuals.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm wary of confusing versions of lme4. Your suggestion with the idLabels does work with my current version of lme4 (1.1-7) however it requires about two dozen zeroes after the decimal point to prevent it plotting all the id labels.